# Are there any specifications that address the environmental conditions items traveling though international post should be able to tolerate?

Tags: standards, specifications

In terms of temperature extremes, air pressure, humidity, shock, ... In determining what ranges to design for in a device are there any standards or at least guidelines either by postal services or governmental departments that can be used to gauge what would be reasonable when designing an electronic device that needs to remain functional during it's traversal of the postal networks around the world.

Or do I need to go with bomb proof?

Comment: There are a whole load of standards and tests that you have to pass to check that medical devices can withstand the temperature, humidity, vibration, compression etc. of shipping/transit, since it could be safety-critical that they continue to function after transit. Have a look here https://met.uk.com/uploads/images/pdfs/How-to-apply-transit-validation-standards.pdf for some inspiration.